# Can I add custom code to google ad banner code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-ads-api, adsense, ads

I am sure google has full enough statistics tool to see ad campaign statistics, but what if I will try to add some JavaScript code to banner code and collect my Own statistics by sending ajax requests?

Will google restrict it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Google ad banners are iframes, and duo to cross-domain rules you cannot inject javascript functions into them.

Comment: what if i adwords user and have created html5 banner by google and want to add to that html some js code?

Comment: I am not publisher I am advertiser